# SafeStrings when using Ember's bindAttr?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, handlebars.js, javascript-framework

This is highly simplified, but I have something like the following:

```
<img src="www.example.com/image.jpg" {{bindAttr alt="view.altText"}} />
```

The `altText` binding comes from a computed property in the view which returns an HTML character like `&#x54;`, but then either Ember or Handlebars (not sure) escapes it for output and what I end up seeing in the code is `&amp;#x54;` which displays in the browser as, literally "&#x54;" instead of the proper HTML character.

In the computed property, I tried `return new Handlebars.SafeString( '&#x54;' )`, but that just threw an error about expecting a string, not an object.

So how do I prevent this?

**Update:** [Here's a github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2398) on the matter. Currently no additional info, but it may get updated before this thread does.

Comment: The value passed to `bindAttr` goes though some internal Ember processing. It sounds like we're not checking for `SafeString`. I'm not sure how difficult it would be to change this, but it's definitely something worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

Handlebars escapes values between {{ }} use {{{ }}} to show output unescaped strings.

Source: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Confirmed, this doesn't work with helpers such as `bindAttr` (I tried `{{{bindAttr alt="view.altText"}}}`)

Comment: The last option I can think of is: 
    alt="{{{unbound view.altText }}}" 
It can't change though.

Comment: The unbound helper wrapped in triple { works. But, as you said, the value isn't bound, so won't change.